# Datatable plugin is not doing as expected

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with jQuery datatables to add pagination, sorting etc functionality to my view I have followed all steps but it is not working, please help me.

I have installed datatable plugin via nuget package manager and tried my best to figure out what the problem is but I am unable to solve this.

Thanks in advance :)

$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#customers ").DataTable();

```
            $("#customers ").on("click",".js-delete", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                    if(result)
                    {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/api/customer/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                                method: "DELETE",
                                success: function () {
                                    button.parents("tr").remove();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
// my bundle file
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/scripts/bootbox.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                        "~/scripts/DataTables/jquery.datatables.js",
                        "~/scripts/DataTables/datatables.bootstrap.js"
                      ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/content/datatables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
//
my shared file where I added scripts to my views

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I think `$("#customers ")` will not work because of the trailing space after the selector.

Comment: @Phiter, trailing space should not be the problem.

Comment: $("#customers ") Is working perfectly. The problem is in $("#customers").Datatable()

Comment: Is there anyone who help me???